# After jibBuildTar, what command to use to load to AWS ECR?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr, jib, amazon-app-runner

Is there an AWS CLI command to simply load my image tar to AWS?  (I do not have docker on my computer at all nor do I want to increase the image size of our CD pipeline as I prefer to keep it very very small since it adds to the time to start in circleCI/githubCI).

Is there a way to do this?

If not, what is the way to do this with docker so I do not have to upload into local docker registry and instead can just directly load to AWS ECR.

Context:
Our CI job builds on the PR 'and' writes a version/build number on the image and into a file in CI on the PR as well BUT NONE OF THIS should be deployed yet until on master branch.  PR cannot merge into master until up to date with master and a merge of master into PR triggers CI again so PR is guaranteed to be latest when landing on master.  This CI job has the artifact that can be deployed by CD (ie. there is no need to rebuild it all over again which takes a while sometimes)
Our CD job triggers on merge to master and reads the artifacts and needs to deploy them to AWS ECR and the image for our CD is very very small having just AWS tooling right now (no need for java, no need for gradle, etc. etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sorry because I don't fully understand your requirements, but maybe you could use tools like [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) in some way.

Among other things, it will allow you to copy your container tar to different registries including AWS ECR without the need to install docker, something like this:

```
skopeo login -u AWS -p $(aws ecr get-login-password) 111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
skopeo copy docker-archive:build/your-jib-image.tar docker://111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myimage:latest
```

This approach is documented as well as a [possible solution](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/2305#issuecomment-590442341) in [this Github issue](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/2305) in the `GoogleContainerTools` repository.

In the issue they recommend another tool named [crane](https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/blob/main/cmd/crane/README.md) which looks similar in its purpose to `skopeo` although I have never tested it.